# Form or asymptotic behaviour of $T(n) =2T(n-1)+n$

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

$T(n) =$ if $n=1$, then time execution is $1$, if $n \geq 2$ then $2T(n-1)+n$

The options are:

1. $T(n) = 2^{n+1} - n - 2$
2. $T(n) = O(n2^n)$
3. $T(n) = \Omega(n)$
4. $T(n) = \theta(2^n)$

Thanks.

Comment: The first choice seems satisfying what the properties you listed exactly.

Comment: I've removed the "complex-analysis" tag since this isn't related to complex analysis.

Comment: Define $T(n) = f(n) -n -2$. And see if you can get $f(n)$ easily.

Comment: The title is wrong; you're not looking for the complexity of this function; you're looking for a closed form for it (option 1) or its asymptotic behaviour (options 2 to 4). This is probably related to the time complexity of a an algorithm, but complexity is a property of the algorithm, not of the function specifying its execution time.

Comment: You're right joriki. Thanks

Comment: Are you allowed to pick more than one option?

Comment: Right JeffE, multiple choices are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the choices you have for the time being, here is how we could start out.

Define $S(n)=2^{-n}T(n)$, then, after multiplying by $2^{-n}$, the recurrence becomes
$$
S(n)=S(n-1)+\frac{n}{2^n}\tag{1}
$$
Equation $(1)$ tells us that $S(n)$ is the finite sum
$$
c+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{2^k}\tag{2}
$$
where $c$ is a constant chosen so that $S(1)=\frac12$.